# web service java wsimport 403

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, wsimport

i'm trying to publish a web service with java, once i created the service and compiled via Eclipse running on the browser at http://localhost:4444/WS/Rubica?wsdl i get the xml.
But trying to import via command line  with wsimport -s . http://localhost:4321/WS/Rubica?wsdl (yesterday with an example it wordked well)

```
C:\Documents and Settings\gcappella\workspace\codenameporc\src>wsimport -s . htt
p://localhost:4321/WS/Rubica?wsdl
analisi di WSDL in corso...


[ERROR] Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://localhost:4321/W
S/Rubica?wsdl

Lettura del documento WSDL: http://localhost:4321/WS/Rubica?wsdl non riuscita pe
rché 1) non è stato possibile trovare il documento; 2) non è stato possibile leg
gere il documento; 3) l'elemento radice del documento non è <wsdl:definitions>.


[ERROR] failed.noservice=Impossibile trovare wsdl:service nei WSDL forniti:

 È necessario fornire almeno un WSDL con almeno una definizione di servizio.


        Analisi di WSDL non riuscita.

C:\Documents and Settings\gcappella\workspace\codenameporc\src>wsimport -s . htt
p://localhost:4444/WS/Rubica?wsdl
analisi di WSDL in corso...


[ERROR] Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://localhost:4444/W
S/Rubica?wsdl

Lettura del documento WSDL: http://localhost:4444/WS/Rubica?wsdl non riuscita pe
rché 1) non è stato possibile trovare il documento; 2) non è stato possibile leg
gere il documento; 3) l'elemento radice del documento non è <wsdl:definitions>.


[ERROR] failed.noservice=Impossibile trovare wsdl:service nei WSDL forniti:

 È necessario fornire almeno un WSDL con almeno una definizione di servizio.


        Analisi di WSDL non riuscita.

C:\Documents and Settings\gcappella\workspace\codenameporc\src>
```

Thank you

Comment: why do you change the port number when you make an import ?

Comment: is for example, in the reality i use the same port, anyway i don't know how to stop a service...i'm trying with endport stop via eclipse but it's not working...